Adhesive used on FFC cable
What type of adhesive is suitable for bonding the tabs back onto FFC cables? (Picture included)
I have attempted with Cyanoacrylate (Super glue) in the past without success.
Context:
The adhesive on these tabs becomes ineffective for many older electronics and the tab is liable to just fall off with minimal handling. Rather than purchasing new FFC cables I would much rather glue them back on as needed.
The cable is not usable without the tab, as the thickness this tab provides is required for the functionality of the locking mechanism on the socket.


What kind of adhesive for end of flat flex cable (FFC)? on the EEVblog Electronics Community Forum has some suggestions. I'm posting this as a comment, and not an answer, since haven't tried any of the suggestions to know how well they work.

A Polyolefin Primer like Loctite SF770 can be used to prime the PET surface to significantly improve the effectiveness of the super glue. I used this with Loctite 406 (difficult to bond materials) and it was suitable for my use case.
I tried using a more available high-bond transfer tape approach using Tesa 61395, but even at 120 Microns it is too thick, in that the connector becomes very difficult to mate.
I have yet to try even thinner transfer tapes, such as the 3M467, perhaps this thickness would prove usable.

If we look at a commercial manufacturer's capabilities we find the following which specifies two possible 3M products:

Stiffeners, attached using thermal bonding or Pressure Sensitive
Adhesive (PSA), provide robust support for flexible PCBs. The choice
of PSA (e.g., 3M Tape, 3M467, or 3M9077) depends on the reflow cycle
requirements and the material to which it will adhere.

467 is a pretty common double-face acrylic adhesive, supplied on a transfer tape, and often used for labels, panels etc. You can find it offered in many places. 9077 is an ultra-high temperature acrylic adhesive and a bit more specialized.
